# Trying to get just "x" coordinate from pos() method python

Tags: python, position, mouseevent, pyqt4

I'm currently having an issue getting just the x position of the cursor so I can place a marker on that x and y location. I'm using QGraphicsScene and view to create this circle object at the location of the mouse when the mouse is clicked. Since the QGraphicsEllipseItem takes 4 arguments it seems I need the x and y coordinate separate not just what the position method gives you since it gives both x and y. How do I split the two coordinates up? Here's the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore    

def paintMarkers(self):
    self.cursor = QtGui.QCursor()
    self.x,y = self.cursor.pos()
    self.circleItem = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(self.x,self.y,10,10)
    self.scene.addItem(self.circleItem)
    self.circleItem.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 1.5))
    self.setScene(self.scene)

def mousePressEvent(self,QMouseEvent):
    self.view.paintMarkers()
```

Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear what your problem is (are you getting an exception? Does it run but you get unexpected output?), but this line looks like the culprit:

```
self.x,y = self.cursor.pos()
```

This will create `x` as an attribute of `self`, and then create a local variable `y` that has no association with `self` at all. If you want both of them to be attributes of `self`, do

```
self.x, self.y = self.cursor.pos()
```

If you were getting an error while trying to do `QGraphicsEllipseItem(self.x,self.y,10,10)`, this would explain why - `self.y` didn't exist, so it would give you an AttributeError.

Comment: okay yeah that was a stupid mistake haha but now I'm getting this error

Comment: TypeError: 'QPoint' object is not iterable

Comment: Oh, I guess you can't do that. Try `self.x, self.y = self.cursor.pos().x(), self.cursor.pos().y()`.

Comment: Ok that seemed to work but now there's like a slight distance difference between where the dot is placed and my actual mouse cursor

Comment: That sounds like a completely different problem, so perhaps you should make a new post.

Comment: @MatthewS2494 If this answer solves your problem, please click the tick mark on the left hand side of the question to mark it as the accepted answer. Also, feel free to upvote answers you find useful by clicking the up arrow just above the tick (although you may need some more reputation before you can vote)