# Qgraphicsview items not being placed where they should be

Tags: python, mouseevent, pyqt4, qgraphicsscene

I recently created a program that will create QgraphicsEllipseItems whenever the mouse is clicked.  That part works! However, it's not in the exact place where my cursor is.  It seems to be slightly higher than where my mouse cursor is.  I do have a QGraphicsRectItem created so maybe the two items are clashing with each other and moving off of one another?  How can I get these circles to be placed on top of the rectangle item? Here's the code

```
class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)

        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.item = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(400, 400, 400, 400)
        self.scene.addItem(self.item)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
    def paintMarkers(self):
        self.cursor = QtGui.QCursor()
        self.x = self.cursor.pos().x()
        self.y = self.cursor.pos().y()
        self.circleItem = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(self.x,self.y,10,10)
        self.scene.addItem(self.circleItem)
        self.circleItem.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 1.5))
        self.setScene(self.scene)

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        #This initializes the main window or form
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,1000,1000)
        self.setWindowTitle("Pre-Alignment system")

        self.view = MyView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
    def mousePressEvent(self,QMouseEvent):
        self.view.paintMarkers()
```

Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the coordinates you are using to place the `QGraphics...Item`s. The first is that the coordinates from `QCursor` are [global screen coordinates](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcursor.html#pos), so you need to use [`self.mapFromGlobal()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapFromGlobal) to convert them to coordinates relative to the `QGraphicsView`.

Secondly, you actually want the coordinates relative to the current `QGraphicsScene`, as this is where you are drawing the item. This is because the scene can be offset from the view (for example panning around a scene that is bigger than a view). To do this, you use [`self.mapToScene()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#mapToScene-5) on the coordinates relative to the `QGraphicsView`.

I would point out that typically you would draw something on the `QGraphicsScene` in response to some sort of mouse event in the `QGraphicsView`, which requires reimplementing things like `QGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent` or `QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent`. These event handlers are passed a `QEvent` which contains the mouse coordinates relative to the view, and so you don't need to do the global coordinates transformation I mentioned in the first paragraph in these cases.

---

### Update

I've just seen your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30893795/1994235) question, and now understand some of the issue a bit better. You shouldn't be overriding the mouse event in the main window. Instead override it in the view. For example:

```
class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)

        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.item = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(400, 400, 400, 400)
        self.scene.addItem(self.item)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
    def paintMarkers(self, event):
        # event position is in coordinates relative to the view
        # so convert them to scene coordinates
        p = self.mapToScene(event.x(), event.y())
        self.circleItem = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(0,0,10,10)
        self.circleItem.setPos(p.x()-self.circleItem.boundingRect().width()/2.0, 
                               p.y()-self.circleItem.boundingRect().height()/2.0)
        self.scene.addItem(self.circleItem)
        self.circleItem.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 1.5))
        # self.setScene(self.scene) # <-- this line should not be needed here

    # Note, I've renamed the second argument `event`. Otherwise you locally override the QMouseEvent class
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.paintMarkers(event)
        # you may want to preserve the default mouse press behaviour,
        # in which case call the following
        return QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self, event)
```

Here we have not needed to use `QWidget.mapFromGlobal()` (what I covered in the first paragraph) because we use a mouse event from the `QGraphicsView` which returns coordinates relative to that widget only.

---

### Update 2

Note: I've updated how the item is created/placed in the above code based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30992957/1994235) answer.

Comment: Ok I think the reason I put the mousePressEvent in the Window class is because I have a button in the window class that when pressed down it will call the mousePressEvent which will call the paintMarkers method. but this does make sense because now I can just do in the window class self.view.mousePressEvent() when the if statement for the button.isChecked() is true...I think

Comment: @MatthewS2494 Well you could pass a reference to the checkbox into the `MyView` class when you instantiate it. That way you could check the state of the checkbox in the `MyView.mousePressEvent`. In general it is prefferrable to handle the events inside the widget you want to do stuff in, rather than trying to do the correct coordinate transforms.

Comment: would you mind writing that line of code I would need? I understand what you're saying but I can't translate it to code.  I have a button called btnPaintDot that when checked will allow the user to draw marks on the scene.  Do I have to create a new object that is a Window object in the MyView class and then call the button?